# ZIP different size of list

Tags: c#

List 2 show only two elements but I need 4 elements

**Address** has got 4 elements

**Association** has got 2 elements

If I will add two more elements to **Association** I will get 4 elements how do it automatically.

```
            DT_createdRentalObject ro = new DT_createdRentalObject();

            //Add Address
            List<Address> la = new List<Address>();
            la.Add(new Address { City = "Arizona" });
            la.Add(new Address { City = "Texas" });
            la.Add(new Address { City = "California" });
            la.Add(new Address { City = "Florida" });
            ro.Address = la.ToArray();

            //Add Association
            List<Association> aso = new List<Association>();
            aso.Add(new Association { AssociationType = "1" });
            aso.Add(new Association { AssociationType = "2" });
            ro.Association = aso.ToArray();

            //Add LandData
            List<LandData> landa = new List<LandData>();
            landa.Add(new LandData { LandRegistrNumber = "12343" });
            landa.Add(new LandData { LandRegistrNumber = "8737" });
            landa.Add(new LandData { LandRegistrNumber = "2456" });
            ro.LandData = landa.ToArray();

            //Object
            List<MasterDataObjectID> mdobid = new List<MasterDataObjectID>();
            mdobid.Add(new MasterDataObjectID { IDType = "TYPID_212_12" });


            //ObjectType
            MasterData mdats = new MasterData();
            mdats.ObjectType = "Flat";
            mdats.ObjectID = mdobid.ToArray();
            ro.MasterData = mdats;

            var list =
                       ro.Address.Zip(ro.Association,
                       (add, asn) => new
                       {
                           ro.MasterData.ObjectID[0].IDType,
                           ro.MasterData.ObjectType,
                           add.City,
                           asn.AssociationType,
                       }
                      );

            var list2 = list.Zip(ro.LandData, (ld, lan) => new
                      {
                          ld.AssociationType,
                          ld.City,
                          ld.IDType,
                          ld.ObjectType,
                          lan.LandRegistrNumber
                      });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you are having. Can you provide more information and perhaps provide an example?

Comment: What is the connection between Addresses, Associations and LandData? So far, the *only* connection is the index in the lists and nothing else. So how should the Address with "Florida" be connected to an Association or LandData? And what do you mean by "how do it automatically"? Automatically add two more elements to Association? What should those new Associations look like? Null objects? Or continue the AssociationTypes with "3" and "4"? The application has no idea and nothing to decide on how to do that "automatically", so you need to define it.